# How can I solve as I am stuck while running npx create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app

[image]I have been trying to create react app but for some reason it keeps getting stuck at the same place. I have tried reinstalling vs-code and node but nothing seems to work. Can anyone help me with this?

[image: I have attached a picture of the terminal. It has been stuck here for around 3 hrs.]

Comment: Please upload a proper screenshot instead of a blurry photo of your screen.

Comment: It is installing packages that it downloads from the web, so maybe your connection is too slow, or you are not allowed to access the resources (e.g. at work behind a proxy).

Comment: @JulienD What do you think I should do?

Comment: To diagnose access to the npm repo, try installing any npm package yourself, e.g. `npm install -g n`. If it works, try to npm install react, react-dom, react-scripts in the same way. If it works, then I have no clue. If it fails, then talk to whoever is responsible for your network/firewall. You can also measure your download speed.

Comment: Maybe also try `npm install -g create-react-app`. Or change the npm version (with `n` installed as in my previous comment)

Comment: Thanks Julien, I'll try. Right now can't do. For past 30 hrs there is no electricity. Amphan cyclone uprooted many poles.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I will get back to you if it worked or not.

Comment: Thanks JulienD thanks for the help. I had to reinstall windows.